# can set 127.0.0.1 to website on Twitter Application settings

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter, settings, oauth

i set:

Website:http://127.0.0.1:8085/

Callback URL :http://127.0.0.1:8085/

is this be permited ,

thanks

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Sign-in-with-Twitter ?

Answer (score 3):

No. [127.0.0.1 means "localhost"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). You need a public IP address/url.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it for local testing, what you can do us make up a non-existent domain or a subdomain for an existing domain, set the callback to that, then edit your HOSTS file or (local DNS if you have it) to point that domain to 127.0.0.1.